# File Uploading Failed when uploading video in php

Tags: php

I am uploading picture in php.it works fine.But when i uploading video it shows file uploading failed.How can to vide file uploading.

Thank You

Comment: Please post the code, no has magic :)

Comment: Please search the site, your question is most certainly already answered.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 4):

PHP couldn't care less what the type of the file is. It DOES care if the file is too large and exceeds specified limits. Videos tends to be MUCH larger than images, so you're probably exceeding the `upload_max_size` limit, amongst others.

Given that you're asking here with so few details, I think it's safe to assume that your upload handling code has absolutely not error checking at all, so I'd suggest reading [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php) first.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.radinks.com/upload/config.php

Check the limit on file size in your php.ini (usually it's 2Mb) maybe you want to change it.